# How to access system process properties in C#?

Tags: windows, wmi

I want to find the  executable path of the system processes, I am following WMI approach, I used Process.EnterDebugMode() for my process to gain privilege to access OS process properties but still when  i call ManagementObject.GetPropertyValue("ExecutablePath") returns null , I am trying this for smss.exe process.

Here is the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int processID = 536; // Just trying with the PID of smss.exe running in my system

        System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode();

        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2", options);

        string NameProperty = "Name";
        string PidProperty = "ProcessId";
        string FullPathProperty = "ExecutablePath";
        string query;
        query = string.Format("select {0}, {1}, {2} from Win32_Process where {1} = {3}", NameProperty, PidProperty, FullPathProperty, processID);
        ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery(query);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery);

        foreach (ManagementObject processEntry in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (processEntry.GetPropertyValue(PidProperty) != null)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(processEntry.GetPropertyValue(PidProperty));
                if (value == processID)
                {
                    if (processEntry.GetPropertyValue(FullPathProperty) != null)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(processEntry[FullPathProperty].ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this info for `smss.exe` process using `wmi`:

```
wmic process where "Caption='smss.exe'" get /value
```

Above command as well as *Task manager* show empty `CommandLine` and `ExecutablePath`:

```
==> wmic process where "Caption='smss.exe'" get Caption, CommandLine, ExecutablePath, ProcessID
Caption   CommandLine  ExecutablePath  ProcessId
smss.exe                               248
```

However, you can get executable path of `smss.exe` (uselessly) using [`where` command](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html):

```
==> where smss.exe
C:\Windows\System32\smss.exe
```

More info in [Critical System Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373646(v=vs.85).aspx)  MSDN article.

> Critical system services cannot be stopped and restarted by the
>   *Restart Manager* without a system restart. Updates to any file or
>   resource in use by one of these services requires a system restart.

Comment: Is there any other approach other than WMI , Can Performance counter functions help?